# How can I stop event to trigger in other magento module

Tags: magento, events, triggers

I have a magento extension which sends user data to an aPI on `newsletter_subscriber_save_before` event. But now I have to send something more to that api and that new var is only available at `newsletter_subscriber_save_after`.

Question is how can I stop `newsletter_subscriber_save_before` for that module with out removing from extenion's config.xml.

If I keep both it will send data twice to api and if I remove `newsletter_subscriber_save_before` from extension it will come again if someone upgrades it.

I don't want disable, as it disable event from everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In config.xml you can use the same event name and thus change the event method to an empty one.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't want disable, as it disable event from everywhere.

But disabling the *observer* is the right way. Exactly for this use case the observer type "disabled" exists.

So if the extension has configured the observer like this:

```
<events>
  <newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
    <observers>
      <some_unique_code>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>extension/observer</class>
        <method>sendSomething</method>
      </some_unique_code>
    </observers>
  </newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
</events>
```

you can disable it in your own extensions config like this:

```
<events>
  <newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
    <observers>
      <some_unique_code>
        <type>disabled</type>
      </some_unique_code>
    </observers>
  </newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
</events>
```

Pay attention that you define this in the same area (frontend, adminhtml or global) and use the same observer code ("some_unique_code" in my example) as the original.

What's important is that your extension gets loaded after the original one, you achieve that with a dependency in your XML in `app/etc/modules/`:

```
<depends>
  <Other_Extension />
</depends>
```

Comment: I tried this but some how it stops triggering event on other places that is why I wrote, "don't want to disable it" anyway, making a empty/fack function instead of disable works for me

Comment: Then something else is wrong. If you look at `Mage_Core_Model_App::dispatchEvent()`, the `disabled` type just does not do anything with the current observer it doesn't prevent other observers from being executed. But overriding the method with a dummy method has the same effect in the end, so it's okay.